# How whatsapp is syncing contacts instantly after updating

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-syncadapter, contentobserver

Can anyone help me out in understanding, How WhatsApp and imo apps are syncing contacts immediately after add/delete/updating contact.

I have tried following method:

1. Tried to register **ContentObserver** in service so that we can get contact which is updated.
2. If we able to deploy a **ContentObserver** to contacts database, how do we differentiate manual and programatic updating of a contact.

Note: I am using **Sync adaptor** to sync the contacts with server but not able to get trigger points for sync process.

Please help me.

Comment: My whatsapp has an "update" button in contact tab, so probably it's not automatic, simply they do it every app's launch or every click on the button

Comment: thanks for the reply,but  i am looking for method, when there is operation(add/delete/update) with respect to contacts data and return contact which is updated, because its taking time to sync all the contacts each time. it will be so good if i just sync updated contacts.

Comment: have you got the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Sync adapter has an option to force sync or immediate sync . [From documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html) the method is similar to the snippet below

```
public void onRefreshButtonClick(View v) {
        ...
        // Pass the settings flags by inserting them in a bundle
        Bundle settingsBundle = new Bundle();
        settingsBundle.putBoolean(
                ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
        settingsBundle.putBoolean(
                ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
        /*
         * Request the sync for the default account, authority, and
         * manual sync settings
         */
        ContentResolver.requestSync(mAccount, AUTHORITY, settingsBundle);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, i am looking for method, when there is operation(add/delete/update) with respect to contacts data and return contact which is updated.

Comment: because its taking time to sync all the contacts each time. it will be so good if i just sync updated contacts.

Comment: The whole process is done in background, so I don't think it won't affect user experience